# Will Apple reject my app if the "Legal" label in a MKMapView is covered by a view?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, appstore-approval

I have a MKMapView and a blurred view (UIVisualEffectView) attached to the bottom, blurring part of the map. As a result, the "Legal" label/button on the map is blurred as well. What can I expect from Apple's approval process, since the button is not manually hidden, just obscured?

Comment: I suspect a rejection as they are pretty formal about ensuring all things within their approved apps are legal. Can I ask, why is it blurred just there?

Comment: Nobody knows what Apple _will_do, probably not even Apple.

Comment: @SASmith The idea was to have a little panel of settings and sliders there for the map. It looks neat with the blur effect, but I'm not sure if I can run with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about what Apple may or may not approve which is always a moving target. In general, questions about app store approval are considered off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)